# Как обновлять файлы в контейнере когда меняются файлы в при разработке c Docker

Tags: node.js, docker

Есть Dockerfile для билда образа с nodejs

```
FROM node:6.9.4


RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app

RUN npm install -g gulp

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Install app dependencies
COPY package.json /usr/src/app/
RUN npm install

# Bundle app source
COPY . /usr/src/app
```

Запускаю образ командой

```
docker run -p 3000:3000 -v `pwd`:/data --rm -it nodejs
```

Все запускается отлично, но я хочу что-бы когда я меняю в IDE любой файл то он также менялся и внутри запущенного контейнера. Как это реализовать?

Comment: Нужно вместо COPY использовать ADD.

Comment: @KoVadim а чем он отличается от COPY?

Comment: никак, либо собирать новое изображение, либо пробрасывать через volume

Comment: @etki можете добавить это в ответ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно смотировать внутрь контейнера рабочую директорию вашего проекта.

```
docker run -p 3000:3000 -v `pwd`:/usr/src/app --rm -it nodejs
```

И так же можно убрать строчки

```
# Bundle app source
COPY . /usr/src/app
```

Comment: Спасибо, я только подумал об этом решении а вы уже дали ответ ))